Eliminate space between mermaid blocks
The following mermaid code:
%%{
  init: {
    'theme': 'base',
    'themeVariables': {
      'tertiaryColor': 'transparent',
      'fontSize': '33'
    }
  }
}%%

block-beta
    columns 3
    a["A label"]:3 b:2 c


    classDef front fill:#696,stroke:#333;
    class a front

produces the following output:

How can I bring all the blocks together, in other words how can I eliminate the spaces between them?
